# Using apply() and its correlaries to replace loops to apply outlier test (e.g.)

Tags: r, for-loop, apply, outliers

I have data from a behavioral task that looks something like this (assuming data frame named data):

```
data <- data.frame(subject = c(rep(8666, 6), rep(5452, 6)), RT = c(714, 877, 665, 854, 1092, 1960, 770, 4551, 1483, 1061, 755, 1090))
data
subject  RT
8666      714
8666      877
8666      665
8666      854
8666     1092
8666     1960
5452      770
5452     4551
5452     1483
5452     1061
5452      755
5452     1090
```

That is, for this question, I'm working with a selection of subjects and reaction times. (All told, 183 subjects with 156 trials each.) Using reshape's cast() function, I've calculated a value for each subject that I'd like to use to exclude certain trials.

```
outl <- function(x) {
    2.5 * mad(x) + median(x)
    }
melteddata <- melt(data, id.vars="subject", measure.vars = "RT")
outliers <- cast(melteddata, subject ~ ., outl)
colnames(outliers)[2] <- "outlier"
```

This outputs something like:

```
  subject    outlier
1    5452   2235.635
2    8666   1517.844
...
```

Now, the way I'd normally do this is to write a loop which, for each unique subject number, compares their RT to the outlier value for that subject:

```
data$outliers <- 0
for(subject in unique(data$subject)) {
    temp <- data[data$subject == subject,]
    temp$outliers <- ifelse(temp$RT > outliers[outliers$subject == subject,]$outlier, 0, 1)
    data[data$subject == subject,]$outliers <- temp$outliers
    }
```

... which marks the RTs of 1960 for subject 8666 and 4551 for 5452 as outliers.

However, I feel like there's got to be a more R way to do this. It feels like apply() should be able to do the same thing, and certainly this takes a long time to run as a loop. Any suggestions?

**Edit:**
I realize I can do this with ddply() from the library(plyr) package instead of using melt() and cast():

```
library(plyr)
outliers <- ddply(data, .(subject), summarize, median = median(RT), mad = mad(RT), outlier = median(RT) + 2.5 * mad(RT))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a try. Turn the outliers data frame into a named vector:

```
out <- outliers$outlier
names(out) <- outliers$subject
```

Then use it as a lookup table to select all the rows of data where the RT column is less than the outlier value for the subject:

```
data[data$RT < out[as.character(data$subject)], ]
```

The `as.character` is necessary since the subject IDs are integers, and you don't want to get, e.g., the 8666th element of `out`.

**Edit** to add a `dplyr` solution:

```
group_by(data, subject) %>% summarize(outlier = 2.5 * mad(RT) + median(RT)) -> outliers
merge(data, outliers)
filter(data, RT < outlier)
```

Comment: Not fancy, but absolutely works.

The question I have then is if you can skip the creating the lookup table step. I realize that I can do it with ddply() instead of melt() and cast(), but I'm wondering if there's a one or two line version of this code that works.

Comment: Not that I can think of, sorry. You can collapse the two lines creating the named vector above into one line: `out <- structure(outliers$outlier, names = outliers$subject)`.

Comment: Actually, with `library(dplyr)`. Create the outliers table `data %>%  group_by(subject) %>% summarize(outlier = 2.5 * mad(RT) + median(RT)) -> outliers`, then add it as an outlier column to the main data `merge(data, outliers)`. Then subset to the rows of interest: `filter(data, RT < outlier)`.